# Select rows from array that are greater than template

Tags: python, performance, numpy

Now I have one 2D Numpy array of float values, i.e. `a`, and its shape is (10^6, 3).
I want to know which rows are greater than `np.array([25.0, 25.0, 25.0])`. And then outputting the rows that satisfy this condition.
My code appears as follows.

```
# Create an empty array
a_cut = np.empty(shape=(0, 3), dtype=float)

minimum = np.array([25.0, 25.0, 25.0])

for i in range(len(a)):
    if a[i,:].all() > minimum.all():
        a_cut = np.append(a_cut, a[i,:], axis=0)
```

However, the code is inefficient. After a few hours, the result has not come out.
So Is there a way to improve the speed of this loop?

Comment: What does it mean for a row to be greater than [25, 25, 25]?

Comment: That `a[i,:].all() > minimum.all()` looks wrong.  Shouldn't it be `a[i,:] > minimum).all()`? Simply do `a[(a > minimum).all(1)]`.

Comment: Don't loop the numpy array unless you absolutely have to; you can just `(a > [25, 25, 25]).all(1)`

Comment: @Alan I mean that all the elements in the row are greater than 25.0

Comment: @Chris you set an argument in the function all(), i.e. all(1). What does that mean?

Comment: @StephenWong it means `axis=1`, i.e. all _rows_ are True, i.e. all rows are greater than 25 ;)

Comment: @Chris since I want to save all the rows that satisfy my condition into another array, so I guess that I have to loop the array. However, the order of magnitude is $10^6$, so the ```for``` loop is ineffective. Maybe there are some ways to achieve my goal.

Comment: @StephenWong `a[(a > minimum).all(1)]`.

Comment: @Divakar If I adopt your code, then how do I output the rows that satisfy this condition?

Comment: @Divakar Thank you, I got it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`np.append` re-allocates the entire array every time you call it. It is basically the same as `np.concatenate`: use it very sparingly. The goal is to perform the entire operation in bulk.

You can construct a mask:

```
mask = (a > minimum).all(axis=1)
```

Then select:

```
a_cut = a[mask, :]
```

You may get a slight improvement from using indices instead of a boolean mask:

```
a_cut = a[np.flatnonzero(mask), :]
```

Indexing with fewer indices than there are dimensions applies the indices to the leading dimensions, so you can do

```
a_cut = a[mask]
```

The one liner is therefore:

```
a_cut = a[(a > minimium).all(1)]
```

Comment: Assuming that I have another array named ```maximum = np.array([50.0, 50.0, 50.0])```,  and I want to let ```a``` satisfies ```maximum > a[i, :] > minimum```. How should the code be modified?

Comment: `max > a & a > min`